# Location of natural roots of a cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Can anybody make this?

The number of natural numbers $n$ such that $n$ is not more than $50$ (equality permitted) and $( (n+(n+(n+.......Up to  infinity )^{1/3})^{1/3})^{1/2} )$ is a natural number . Then find the number.  I made it using basic mathematics. My answer is 0. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $1)$ the given expression does not seem to be a polynomial (in $n$) $2)$ For positive $n$, the expression is clearly positive, so $0$ only occurs for $n=0$

Comment: What's the pattern with the fractional exponents? All $\frac13$ except the outermost, which is $\frac12$?

Comment: It's not clear what the 5 dots represent. You have exponents of $\frac13,\frac13, \frac12$, so the pattern of exponents isn't clear, as well as the depth of nesting of the parenthesis

Comment: The 1st exponent is 1÷2. And after that all the exponents are 1÷3. There were some problems with the question and so I have made an edit. The dots mean here , upto infinity. The given expression is not a polynomial on n. But you may require to use the concepts of polynomials (as I did).